# How to permanently change default page margins in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I know how to change page margins in Google Docs, but how to change them permanently? Right now I have to change them every single time I create a new document which is pretty laborious. Is there a way to register this change once and for all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "Set as default" button to set default page margins in Google Docs.

1. Open a document that has the margins you want as default.
2. Go to File > Page setup...
3. Click the "Set as default" button.

Now when you make a new document, Google Docs will use those margins.

Comment: Oh dear, how could I missed that button. Thanks :)